# Building SQL query for a table structure

Tags: sql, mysql

For the following table structure
Booking
Fields - BookingID(Primary key), CustID, SeatPref

I want to get the SeatPref which is preferred by most CustIDs.

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select
    seatpref,
    count(seatpref) as PrefCount
from
    Bookings b
group by
    seatpref
order by
    count(seatpref) desc
```

Comment: Beat me by a just a little bit!  It seems we agree, +1

Answer (score 2):

I think

```
SELECT SeatPref, count(SeatPref) AS NumCusts
FROM your_table
GROUP_BY SeatPref
ORDER_BY NumCusts
```

should do it.